# C# Maui app not consuming local ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core-webapi, maui

I am trying to consume data from an ASP.NET Core Web API through a `GET` request, and I get a connection attempt failed error, because the connected party did not respond properly (10.0. 2.2:5019).

When I used a mock API from a previous project, I got the data with no exceptions.

I tried many solutions to configure the Web API, but none helped.

Comment: How did you start that web app? IISExpress only accepts localhost requests, which you cannot use from a maui app. Can you use IIS?

Comment: i disabled ssl and i am using http with 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

Comment: By default IIS Express **ONLY** accepts localhost requests.  This is most likely a networking issue and you need to do some basic network debugging to isolate the problem

Comment: i  disabled fire wall and tested but nothing changed

Comment: no none of them is a startup project

Comment: Two of us have pointed out that IIS Express will not accept remote requests and you seem to be ignoring this advice.  If you are using Android or iOS requests will appear to be remote even if you are running an emulator on the same PC.  You can easily test this by attempting to connect to your service from the browser on the **test device or emulator**

Comment: In case you don't know :IISExpress is the default webserver when you run a webapp from Visual Studio. It is simpler to use than full IIS, but has limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed 10.0.2.2 to localhost and it worked